# Burninate "shorten"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, tags

[shorten](/questions/tagged/shorten) is used on 79 SO questions whenever the poster is trying to shorten anything at all. It's another one of those keywords that doesn't need to be a tag. I say we kill it with fire. What say you?

Comment: Me sayeth yes, most certainly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the tag from all 74 questions; it should be automatically deleted within 24 hours.

[image]